# ClassNotFoundException Exception

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jersey-1.0

I have developed a project using jersey 2 and spring 4,but i had to replace jersey 2 with jersey 1.19,when I did this i am getting an exception called "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties", when running on tomcat server.Is the migration from jersey 2 to jersey 1.19 causing this exception?.Thanks

My web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- Spring Listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Jersey Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FITransXT</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <!-- Register resources and providers -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mobileware.fitransxt</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FITransXT</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- loading Spring Context for registering beans with ApplicationContext -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/FITransXT-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>



</web-app>
```

my Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <!-- <dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencyManagement> -->
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mobileware.fitransxt</groupId>
    <artifactId>FITransXT</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>FITransXT-Impl</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.mobileware.fitransxt</groupId>
 <artifactId>FITransXT-Type</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1</version>
 </dependency> 
 <dependency>
 <groupId>com.mobileware.fitransxt</groupId>
 <artifactId>FITransXT-BOImpl</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <!--  <dependency>
 <groupId>com.mobileware.fitransxt</groupId>
 <artifactId>FITransXT-DaoImpl</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1</version>
 </dependency> -->
    <!-- Jersey core Servlet 2.x implementation -->
<!--     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
          <scope>compile</scope> 
    </dependency> -->
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>

   <!-- Jersey JSON Jackson (2.x) entity providers support module -->
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>


    <!-- Jersey extension module providing support for Spring 3 integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.ext/jersey-bean-validation -->


    <!-- Spring Framework-4.x -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>  
<version>${spring.version}</version>  
  </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jersey.version>1.19</jersey.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>
        <jdk.source.version>1.8</jdk.source.version>
        <jdk.target.version>1.8</jdk.target.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Dependency Tree

```
-- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ FITransXT-Web ---
[INFO] com.mobileware.fitransxt:FITransXT-Web:war:0.0.1
[INFO] +- com.mobileware.fitransxt:FITransXT-Impl:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mobileware.fitransxt:FITransXT-Type:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.mobileware.fitransxt:FITransXT-BOImpl:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.mobileware.fitransxt:FITransXT-BOIntf:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.mobileware.fitransxt:FITransXT-Type:jar:0.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- com.mobileware.fitransxt:FITransXT-DaoImpl:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.mobileware.fitransxt:FITransXT-Dao:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (com.mobileware.fitransxt:FITransXT-Type:jar:0.0.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2.17)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.6)
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] \- org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile
```

Edited:
on console:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.core.util.FeaturesAndProperties
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: update maven in your project

Comment: Do you get this when running something built by maven, or when running in IDE?

Comment: @Durgpal Singh,How to update maven? i mean is it the version or what?

Comment: @Tobb. I got this exception while running project on tomcat.

Comment: @MohdToufeeqkhan update maven means download all the dependency of project threw maven.

Comment: Ok, so you build a war and run it on tomcat? Perhaps tomcat ships with jersey 2.x? You should inspect the classpath of your war (as well as any tomcat classpath) to see if you can find any file of jersey 2.x

Comment: Also, show a bit more of your stacktrace, to see which framework is actually trying to reach the class that is not found.

Comment: @Tobb yes I did build a war file and ran on tomcat.And could you please tell me how to inspect classpath of war and tomcat classpath

Comment: @Tobb i have added console view, hope this will give you some idea,please guide what to do.

Comment: try this, mvn clean install -U, let me know if won't work

Comment: @rish. i am little new to maven. could you please tell where to run this command,inside project root folder ?

Comment: @rish ,I tried this but didn't work

Comment: @Durgpal Singh. I have downloaded dependencies throw maven only.

Comment: okay, go to .m2 directory and search for lastupdate and removed all related files, check if this work or not

Comment: @rish are these .properties files?

Comment: nope, if you are using windows go to C:/Users/username and search for .m2 directory

Comment: i am using linux and i know  the location. so  do I need to delete all these files?

Comment: I have deleted all lastupdated files, but didn't work.

Comment: can you remove m2 directory then try to clean and install maven, first close your IDE and remove target, .settings from your project root directory before installing maven

Comment: after doing what you have suggested.  i am gettin this when running on tomcat.  Feb 28, 2017 8:34:07 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
    INFO: No provider classes found.

Comment: you are getting 404 on browser? If yes then check your path. By the way, your first problem got solved

Comment: @rish deleting m2 folder have worked for me ...thanks everyone for their responses

Comment: @MohdToufeeqkhan I have answered of your question, bcz it's worked for you, accept the answer this may help to others who's facing same kind of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways to handle these kind of problem-

First close your IDE and remove target, .setting and .classpath from your project directory.

1) Double check if you have multiple dependency of same with different version in pom.xml, if yes remove it and run command **mvn clean install -U**. If it's not work then

2) Find .m2 directory and inside this directory search for lastupdate file and remove all these files and run command **mvn clean install -U**. If it's not work then

3) Remove .m2 direcory and clean and install maven.